# How can I set the text size relative to the plot dimension in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot 2, I can set the size of all texts using theme_grey(base_size=16). This font size looks fine if I export the plot in a 400*400 PNG. However, it looks too small if I export the plot in a 800*800 PNG. How can I set the text size relative to the plot dimension?

Comment: One thing that would help is if you create a reproducible example (sample data, code, etc.).  That might help folks find a solution that fits you needs.  That being said, what happens if you set `base_size = 32` when exporting to 800*800 ?

Comment: That certainly would work. I am just too lazy to change the code every time I make a plot. I guess I can make the font size = round (a/25) where a is the dimension of the plot. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: I haven't tried it but I was thinking along the lines of scaling.  I think the more general question is, how do you increase the resolution but keep the font size something you can read (e.g. keep the same size).